# Variable in jQuery selector error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put a variable inside a jQuery selector. However I am assuming that I am breaking some form of a syntax rule. Please let me know if you can spot the mistake:

```
var names = ["JakeP97", "Trishy", "Puffs", "Evilgenious", "Joeyc", "TheKid"];
var ballots = ["#book1", "#book2", "#book3", "#book4", "#book5", "#book6"];

function splitName(plName,ballotNum) {
    var halfplName = Math.round(plName.length / 2);
    var firstplname = plName.substr(0, halfplName);
    var lastplName = plName.substr(halfplName, plName.length);
    $(ballotNum 'ul.hardcover_front').find('li:nth-child(2)').html(firstplname);
    $(ballotNum 'ul.hardcover_back').find('li:nth-child(1)').html(lastplname);
}

for (i=0; i<ballots.length; i++) {
    splitName(names[i],ballots[i]);
}
```

Error takes place on the following lines:
`$(ballotNum 'ul.hardcover_front')`

The desired result would be:
`$('#book1 ul.hardcover_front')`, `$('#book2 ul.hardcover_front')` etc, all the way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's $(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_front'), you're missing a + to join a string. also make sure ballotNum has a hash at the front.

Answer (score 4):

You need to concat the string and variables.

```
$(ballotNum + ' ul.hardcover_front').find('li:nth-child(2)').html(firstplname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `+` sign. Since you are concatenating the variable with a string, you need to use `+` sign:

```
$(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_front')
```

So this lines:

```
$(ballotNum 'ul.hardcover_front').find('li:nth-child(2)').html(firstplname);
$(ballotNum 'ul.hardcover_back').find('li:nth-child(1)').html(lastplname);
```

will change to:

```
$(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_front').find('li:nth-child(2)').html(firstplname);
$(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_back').find('li:nth-child(1)').html(lastplname);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_front').find('li:nth-child(2)').html(firstplname);
$(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_back').find('li:nth-child(1)').html(lastplname);
```

I think you forgot adding `+`.